# Is there any QT6 QML video .sdp media type alternative in windows platform?

Tags: windows, video, qml, h.264, qt6

In Qt5 QML windows platform i was use video type to display video. I was give video type' s source a .sdp file. Video format is h264 rtppay and trasmitting with UDP packets. I have K-Lite_Codec_Pack installed on my device.
*Qt6 QML video type doesn't support .sdp media format type.

Is there a good alternative to that in Qt6 QML to display video in windows platform?

Video type were like follows:

```
Video {
     id: videoType
     fillMode: VideoOutput.Stretch
     anchors.fill: parent
     source: "file:./../VideoConfig/video.sdp"
}
```

.sdp file were like follows:

```
v=0
m=video 6666 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 192.168.11.192
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
```

That works in QT5.

Comment: Can you confirm whether the video source is a file or a stream? Your QML source "file:./../VideoConfig/video.sdp" implies it is a file resource, whereas the description implies it's a stream.

Comment: Video source is a stream.